# Laplace transform and Laguerre Polynomials

Tags: special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, laplace-transform

What is the kernel $K(t)$ of the following Laplace transform equation:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-(x+y)t} K(t) dt= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\varphi_{n}^{\alpha}(x)\varphi_{n}^{\alpha}(y),$$
where $\varphi_{n}^{\alpha}(x)=(\frac{n!}{\Gamma(\alpha+n+1)})^{1/2} \frac{e^{x}}{n!} \frac{d^{n}}{x^{n}}(e^{-x}x^{n})$ is the normalized Laguerre polynomial. If the result is not known, where can I find this type of equation?

Comment: I presume your expression for $\varphi^\alpha_n(x)$ is missing a factor $x^{-\alpha}$ before the derivative, and a factor $x^\alpha$ after the derivative, and that the denominator $x^n$ should be $dx^n$.

Comment: Yes you are right sorry

Answer (score 2):

Let me check this for $\alpha=0$, when $\varphi_n^\alpha(x)=L_n(x)$ is the Laguerre polynomial. The completeness relation is (see eq. 1.10 of [Li and Wong - Integral and series representations of the Dirac delta function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1943))
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty L_n(x)L_n(y)=e^{(x+y)/2}\delta(x-y).$$
This depends on both the sum and difference of $x$ and $y$, so the representation given in the OP, which depends only on $x+y$, does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is it possible to put $K(t)=\delta(x-y) e^{(x+y)/2}e^{(x+y)t}e^{-t}$?

Comment: sure, but it's kind of pointless to allow $K(t)$ to depend on $x$ and $y$ as well, then why introduce this integral?